# Why does owl-eyed mean intoxicated?

Tags: etymology, slang

The *Survey of College Words and Phrases* by Eugene H. Babbitt published in 1900 lists the word *owl-eyed* to mean *intoxicated.* Any ideas as to why an owl-eyed person is an intoxicated person?

Comment: I find it odd that _The Survey of College Words and Phrases_ by Eugene H. Babbitt appears to be mentioned in only three places on the entire Internet: both of them questions by you (though one of the other two is in an answer given by a different user). What exactly _is_ this book, and where do you have it from?

Comment: ISBN-13: 9781130967814. Lots of digital copies on Ebay and Amazon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes people who get drunk get red/bloodshot eyes, like [this](http://www.replacemycontacts.com/images/learning/istock_000020506215_extrasmall.jpg):

[image: human bloodshot eye]

or [this](http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lxnsu8K4qk1r7cpoqo1_500.jpg):

[image: owl bloodshot eye]
.

Comment: That owl is completely smashed.

Comment: Your answer lots spot on, it could also be possible that this relates to drugs, such as cocaine as well, the 1900s was a rife period for the use of cocaine amongst most classes. Meaning it could have been a misinterpretation at the time or even a slang only the college students ever really understood. I'm not affirming, but it's possible, due to the nature of cocaine's effects.